# Do WiFi connections typically expire after X many hours?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Do WiFi connections typically expire after X many hours?

Here's the scenario that prompts the question.

A wifi router is broadcasting a wifi signal. A phone that does nothing but stream music connects to this router via wifi. After X many hours the connection is dropped. I have not pin-pointed the number of hours between the connection being established, and the connection being dropped. The phone must re-join the wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

No, Wi-Fi connections do not typically expire after some amount of time. Wi-Fi connections typically persist indefinitely.

Many Wi-Fi APs (wireless routers) provide mechanisms by which the owner or admininstrator could implement a time limit or a reauthentication interval to periodically kick clients off, but those features are usually disabled by default.